# How to georeference to the US base in Guantanamo?

Tags: carto, geocoding

I make my first steps on CartoDB. I would like to assign data to the US enclave at Guantanamo in Cuba and I can't. Yet the CartoDB base map shows the enclave.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't?

Answer (score 1):

If our geocoder doesn't georeference the point you could add the point yourself. It's quite easy:

You can get the coordinates searching (in Google Maps) for "Guantanamo Bay Detention Camp, Caimanera, Guantanamo, Cuba"

And here you have the coordinates they return: 19.902976, -75.100126

You can add or edit a point, edit the "the_geom" column and add or replace the values with the lat and long above.